# CSS div with child inline-block with child display none maintains height

Tags: responsive-design, css

```
<div>
    <div style="display:inline-block;">
        <div style="display:none"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I'm trying to understand this inline-block behaviour. This is a simplified version of a layout issue I ran into with some responsive elements in my header and menu bars. If the intermediate div is anything but inline-block, the entire nested block will have no height (or visibility, I'm not sure). However, if the intermediate div is an inline-block, it appears to display none with the innermost child (it's shaded in Firebug code, so I'm assuming it's hidden), however the the parent div maintains some sort of default height.

The best work-around I've found, which also sheds some light on where the default height is coming from, is to give the outer div a line-height of 0 or 1px. It still shows a 2-3px height which I can live with for my particular design. However, I can imagine cases where this work-around won't work, so it seems a bit like a hack.

I'm interested in understanding why this particular structure is behaving this way. So far, with my tests, it appears to be unique in terms of not collapsing when its children have no display. When understood properly, is it a bug or the logical result of the way the nested displays are interacting? Is there a better way to control it than with line-height? Can it be forced to display no height at all?

I'm not interested in JS solutions, or solutions which suggest work-arounds involving avoiding inline-blocks. Adding CSS to the existing proposed structure is fine. In my mind, the best solution would show no height for the structure with the least consequences for elements displayed inside the structure when display is not set to none. My question is as much theoretical as it is practical.

Comment: please provide a jsfiddle. Cheers

Comment: Please could you possibly explain what you want in terms of [this](http://jsfiddle.net/jbutler483/74h8ae7a/2/) for clarification purposes (I've just placed your styling into css classes).? Also, why don't you just include a min-height attribute?

Answer (score 0):

**Is it a bug or the logical result of the way the nested displays are interacting?**

Inline elements (inline-block and inline - which both recreate your issue), have white space after them. This has the same effect as a single SPACE U+0020 character, by HTML specifications. This is what causes your parent div to have a height.

**Is there a better way to control it than with line-height? Can it be forced to display no height at all?**

It depends, really, on what you consider 'better'. You could float the 'middle' element, instead of displaying it inline. (This may require you to clear the floats in the parent element - there is a common fix for this called clearfix)

Here is sample code showing this method in effect:

HTML:

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="middle">
        <div class="final">asdf</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.middle{ float:left; }
.final{ display:none; }

/* Shading to show sizes of divs */
div { border:1px solid; background:rgba(0,0,0,.2); }

/* Clearfix */
.parent:before,
.parent:after {
    content: " ";
    display: table;
}
.parent:after {
    clear: both;
}
```

Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/16xp2m3L/2/